# Not Able to Enable Snapping Management on top of a feature service

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, snapping

Can you please take a look at **[This Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/cwbtvro4/)** and let me know why I am not able to set up and enable Snapping on top of following feature Service? What I need is snapping to all features in mouse hover/over of each?

```
var map;
require(["esri/map",
  "esri/SnappingManager",
  "esri/layers/FeatureLayer",
  "dojo/keys",
  "dojo/domReady!"
], function(Map, SnappingManager, FeatureLayer, keys) {
  map = new Map("map", {
    basemap: "topo",
    center: [-88.158805, 41.786075],
    zoom: 18
  });

  var propertyLayer = new FeatureLayer("https://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/CommunityAddressing/FeatureServer/0", {
    mode: FeatureLayer.MODE_ONDEMAND,
    outFields: ["*"]
  });
  map.addLayers([propertyLayer]);

  var snapManager = map.enableSnapping({
    snapKey: keys.CTRL
  });
  var layerInfos = [{
    layer: propertyLayer,
    snapToVertex: true
  }];
  snapManager.setLayerInfos(layerInfos);

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To enable the Snapping, you must be in some "drawing" mode. As you did it in [your other demo](https://jsfiddle.net/6uweoank/)

```
$("#add").on("click", function() {
  var toolbar = new esri.toolbars.Draw(map);
  toolbar.activate(esri.toolbars.Draw.POINT);
});
```

If not, you do not need to snap anything, because you will not draw anything =)